# How long does it take for one thread to notify another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, c++-chrono

I want to measure how long it takes for a condition variable to notify another waiting thread. I wrote this example to try to capture the time difference:

```cpp
bool ready{false};
mutex m;
condition_variable cv;
decltype(chrono::steady_clock::now()) t1;
decltype(chrono::steady_clock::now()) t2;

void notifying_thread() {
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lg{m};
        ready = true;
    }
    t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cv.notify_one();
}

void waiting_thread() {
    unique_lock<mutex> ul{m};
    cv.wait(ul, [] { return ready; });
    t2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
}

int main() {
    auto f1{async(notifying_thread)};
    auto f2{async(waiting_thread)};
    f1.get();
    f2.get();
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " µs\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Did I do this right? Do I have my `chrono::steady_clock::now()`s in the right place? On average the time is ~25 µs, but sometimes it's even negative. How can it be negative? Shouldn't `t1` always start before `t2`? Is the launch policy for `async` relevant?

Comment: I would take a timestamp before and after the call to `notify_one`. It doesnt block, but its also not immediately. Also I think you might have spurious wake ups in the short time window when `ready = true;` was already set but `cv.notify_one();` was not yet called. If this happens the time can be expected to be negative

Comment: and if `notifying_thread` starts "long" before `waiting_thread` you are measuing that time, not the time it takes to notify.

Comment: @molbdnilo I disagree. I think it should be guaranteed that `t1` has an earlier timestamp than `t2` because `t2` cannot be set until after wait returns true, and at that point `t1` has already been set. What do you mean independent timelines?

Comment: you miss spurious wakeups as I mentioned before. It can happen that `wait` spuriously unblocks. Thats what the predicate is for: It only unblocks when `ready` is true, but that happens before `t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now(); cv.notify_one();`

Comment: @user3100212 _"`t2` cannot be set until after `wait` returns `true`"_ — You missed the possible case where `wait` (1) isn't called in `wait` (2), not even once. See the answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are missing spurious wake ups in your reasoning. The [`std::condition_variable::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) overload with predicate is equivalent to

```
while (!stop_waiting())
{
    wait(lock);
}
```

`wait(lock)` can return even if the condition variable was not notified. Thats what the predicate is for. When there is spurious wake up you keep looping until the condition is fullfilled.

Due to spurious wake up it can happen that `wait(lock)` unblocks before the other thread called `notify_one` but after it has set `ready = true`. In that case `t2` can be an earlier time than `t1`.

Moreover, as DanielLangr pointed out in a comment, when the condition is already fullfilled before even entering the above loop then `wait(lock)` is never called. Also in this case, `t2` can be earlier than `t1`.

Moreover, the two threads do not start immediately. If `notifying_thread` starts and `waiting_thread` starts only some time later, then you are basically measuring that time, not the time it takes to notify the condition variable.

Comment: AFAIK, spurious wakeups are relatively rare. But here, what also can happen, is that the `ready` flag is set first before the `while` loop is reached. Therefore, `wait` isn't call at all. If this happens, those time measurements are completely unsynchronized.

Comment: @DanielLangr good point. I was too focused on one counter example and missed the more obvious one